# Trouble Connecting to compose.io mongodb instance with mongoose

Tags: node.js, ssl, mongoose, compose-db

I am using these instructions:
https://help.compose.com/docs/connecting-to-mongodb#mongoose-node-and-compose

This is the connection string they gave me:

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb://*****:******@aws-us-west-2-portal.1.dblayer.com:15782,aws-us-west-2-portal.0.dblayer.com:15782/mydbname?ssl=true
```

This is the code I am trying:

```
certFileBuff = [fs.readFileSync(MONGO_CERT_PATH)]
options = {
     mongos: true,
     sslCA: certFileBuff,
     sslValidate: false,
     ssl: true
}

mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, options)
```

At this point I get Authentication Failure errors:

if i remove `?ssl=true` from the connection string I get the error:
`no mongos proxy available`

Does anyone have mongoose working with compose.io recently?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using sharding in mongo set `mongos` to `false`.
You can read about sharding in mongo here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/

Comment: Apparently with compose.io it is required to use mongos (according to their documentation) They are telling me to switch up the mongos: true into mongo: {...vars}  but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out. I had a password that didn't get along with the connection string. I changed the password to something shorter and it worked. fwiw the password that didn't work was: **tapasleechframegoldrabbitsauceb88** (Obviously I'm not using anymore)

What I learned:
If you get a `mongos proxy error` its probably bad config. Make sure `ssl=true` is set on the connection string and `ssl: true` in your config.

If you get `code: 18` authentication error then the password is either wrong or not formatted properly.

Here is my final working code:

```
const MONGO_URI = mongodb://****:*****@aws-us-west-2-portal.1.dblayer.com:15782,aws-us-west-2-portal.0.dblayer.com:15782/dbName?ssl=true


let ca, options = {}

if(MONGO_CERT_PATH) {
    try {
        ca = fs.readFileSync(encodeURI(MONGO_CERT_PATH))
        options = {
            mongos: {
                ssl: true,
                sslValidate: true,
                sslCA: [ ca ]
            }
        }
    } catch(err) {
        logger.warn('mongo ssl cert missing')
    }
}

let db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (e) => logger.error('connection error:', e))
db.once('open', () => {
    logger.info('db connected')
})

mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, options)
```